# How to force updating of the bower.json dependencies per default using Bower?

Tags: dependencies, config, bower, dependency-management, bower-install

When a package is being [`install`](http://bower.io/docs/api/#install)ed/[`uninstall`](http://bower.io/docs/api/#uninstall)ed, the option/flag `--save`/`--save-dev` can be used, in order to update the `dependencies`/`devDependencies` section of the `bower.json` file, e.g.:

```
$ bower install bootstrap --save
```

**`bower.json`**

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "...",
  "description": "...",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.4"
  }
}
```

Most it is the wished behavior. And it's annoying, when one fogets this flag and commits/deploys the project without the Bower dependencies and has to include the later one by one manually.

So, my question: **Is it possible / How to make the `bower.json` `dependencies` section the default behavior?**

Answer (score 0):

Just found this [discussion](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1040) on the Bower GitHub page. The issue is not implemented (yet).